# Moving multiple columns in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having a problem adding and moving multiple columns in a JTable.

I have data for certain dates in each column and a column header. All is fine on the move itself but after I add and move the next column it resets.

I haven't altered the location of any columns anywhere else in the project.

Here's an example of the output (headers only):

`| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |`

Add header "1" and move to index 0:

`| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |`

Add header "2" and move to index 1:

`| 5 | 2 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 1 |`

Add header "3" and move to index 2:

`| 5 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 1 | 2 |`

and some code to follow it up (Problem location specified by "<<<<"'s):

```
 public void recalculateTableDates(String start, String end, Double defaultValue) {     
    String startDate = getTblDetails().getColumnName(1);
    String endDate = getTblDetails().getColumnName(getTblDetails().getColumnCount()-1);

    int sMonth = Integer.parseInt(start.substring(4, 6));
    int sYear = Integer.parseInt(start.substring(0, 4));
    int eMonth = Integer.parseInt(end.substring(4, 6));
    int eYear = Integer.parseInt(end.substring(0, 4));

            // gets distance between 2 values
            // (Used elsewhere in project, working as intended)
    int duration = getDuration(sMonth, sYear, eMonth, eYear);

    Vector<Double> data = new Vector<Double>(duration);

    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
         data.addElement(defaultValue);
    }

    for(int i = 1, mCount = sMonth, yCount = sYear; i < duration+1; i++) {
        String yyyymm = String.valueOf(yCount)+String.format("%02d", mCount++);





                    // Adds to beginning - PROBLEM HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        if(yyyymm.compareTo(startDate) < 0) {
            getModel().addColumn(yyyymm, data);
            moveColumn(tblDetails.getColumnCount()-1, i);

        } else if(yyyymm.compareTo(endDate) > 0) {
                              // THIS IF STATEMENT WORKING AS INTENDED
                  getModel().addColumn(yyyymm, data);
        }

        if(mCount > 12) {
            mCount = 1;
            yCount++;
        }

    }

    int length = getTblDetails().getColumnCount()-1;
    System.out.println(duration + " " + length);
    if(length > duration) {
        TableColumnModel colModel = getTblDetails().getColumnModel();
        for(int i = length; i > duration; i--) {
            colModel.removeColumn(colModel.getColumn(i));
        }
    }

    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}



    // Moves column in table
 private void moveColumn(int column, int targetIndex) {
      getTblDetails().moveColumn(column, targetIndex);
 }
```

I realise the code is a bit messy. Been running up and down trying to change this and that to fix it.

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this? I don't have extensive experience with JTable.

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: my curiosity, why is column labeled with "1" moved to the end after column "2" is added to JTable, the same for column "3", I miss there logics for ..... or this could be  logics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a column is added to the model the TableColumns for the table are rebuilt from the model so you lose all the customization that has been done to the table. This means you lose any custom renderer that may have been added and you lose the reordering of columns.

To prevent this you can do the following when you initially create the table:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
```

Because the TableColumn is not automatically created you need to do this your self the the code would be something like:

```
String header = "Col" + (table.getColumnCount() + 1);
model.addColumn( header );

//  AutoCreate is turned off so create table column here

TableColumn column = new TableColumn( table.getColumnCount() );
column.setHeaderValue( header );
table.addColumn( column );
```

Comment: I solved this by directly altering the data and identifier vectors from the model directly. Seemed simpler. Thanks for the help though